# how to echo hidden form fields based on conditional check boxes in php?

Tags: php, forms, field, hidden, checkbox

I want the form to echo the hidden form fields based on which check box is checked, note i need to echo the hidden form fields before the submit button is pressed, since it is going to paypal. Here is what i have so far -

```
<?php       
echo ('<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">');
echo ('<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">');
echo ('<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">');
echo ('<input type="hidden" name="business" value="youremail@mail.com">');
echo ('<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="US">'); 
echo ('<input type="checkbox" name="camp1" value="a">');
echo ('<input type="checkbox" name="camp2" value="b">');    

if (isset($_POST['camp1'])) {

echo ("<input type='hidden' name='item_name_1' value='beach ball'>");
("<input type='hidden' name='amount_1' value=50'>");
}
if (isset($_POST['camp2'])) {

echo ("<input type='hidden' name='item_name_2' value='towel'>");
("<input type='hidden' name='amount_2' value='20'>");
}
echo ("<input type='submit' value='PayPal'>");
("</form>");
?>
```

I have also tried replacing

```
if (isset($_POST['camp1'])) {
```

with something like

```
if(IsChecked('camp1','a')) {
```

With no luck.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not submiting the form then there is no `POST` or `GET` method executed and you are calling in your if statement a variable from POST `$_POST['camp1']` and you will never get that value. An alternative to solve this could be using JS or jQuery, example:

**Your modified PHP:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Paying process</title>
</head>
<script scr="jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script scr="functions.js" type="text/javascript" />
<body>
<?php       
echo ('<form id="payForm" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">');
echo ('<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">');
echo ('<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">');
echo ('<input type="hidden" name="business" value="youremail@mail.com">');
echo ('<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="US">'); 
echo ('<input type="checkbox" name="camp1" value="a">');
echo ('<input type="checkbox" name="camp2" value="b">');    
echo ('<div id="productInfo" style="display:none;"></div>');
echo ("<input type='submit' value='PayPal'>");
echo ("</form>");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**functions.js file:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#payForm").submit(function(e){
       if($('#productInfo').html() == ''){
           //if there is no product in the hidden div, prevent the submit and show msg.
           alert('Please select at least one product');
           e.preventDefault();
       }
    });

    // event when user clicks a checkbox
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function(){
       var checked = $(this).attr('checked');
       if(checked){
          var value = $(this).val();
          $.post('product.php', { value:value }, function(data){
              // data = 0 - means that there was an error or no product
              if(data != 0){
                 // At this point you will have your "a" or "b" products in hidden
                 // Also submit button will appear
                 // This means that everything was Ok and the user selected a product
                 $('#productInfo').append(data);
              } else {
                 // data = 0
                 alert('Please try again.');
              }
          });
       }
    });

});
```

**product.php file** (used in the jQuery post):

```
  <?php
    if ($_POST && isset($_POST['value'])) {

        // db connection
        $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
        if (!$link) {
           // error happened
           print(0);
        }
        mysql_select_db('mydb');

        // sanitize the value
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value']);

        // start the query - I am assuming one :-)
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE Id = '$value'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

        // check if the product exists
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){                                                 
          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            if($value == 'a'){
               echo ("<input type='hidden' name='item_name_1' value='".$row['product_name']."' />");
               echo ("<input type='hidden' name='amount_1' value='".$row['product_price']."'>");    
            } else {
               echo ("<input type='hidden' name='item_name_2' value='".$row['product_name']."' />");
               echo ("<input type='hidden' name='amount_2' value='".$row['product_price']."'>");    
            }                               
          }
        } else {
          // no product found
          print(0);                                       
        }
  ?>
```

Now you are able to submit with your hidden values, item 1 or 2 or both only when the user selects at least one product.

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Right, so is there a way to see if the checkbox is checked without using post? Something more along the lines of the IsCheked

Comment: I am editing my post an giving you an example, try using jQuery with PHP, I am coding now, wait 2 minutes and check my post again :-)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to get PHP to perform client-side behavior, which is not possible. PHP renders the page once, when the user first requests the page, and doesn't do anything after that until they submit the form or load another page (or until some other communication occurs, if you're using ajax or jquery). If you want the contents of the page to change in response to clicking a checkbox, you'll need to incorporate some javascript.

Comment: ok that's a good start thanks, ill start looking for a solution with js